# how to have the same route path hit different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm having an issue with react router and its routing path.

I have a couple of links, say

1. localhost:3000/a
2. localhost:3000/b
3. localhost:3000/c

and my route is set up as so:

```
<Route exact path="/:cat" component={Post} />
```

My issue is that whenever I go to one of the three URLs, i.e. 1 -> 3, it will only load page 1, as all of them meet the criteria (i.e. `path="/:cat"`). Am I correct to assume that it won't render each path as they are referred to as ONE route, hence it doesn't need to be rendered as the "state" hasn't changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its one route and any matching path (/a or /b) will render that Post component.

`<Route exact path="/:cat" component={Post} />`

This route will allow you to render Post component for each url, that starts from / and this component will have the actual url inside this.props.routeParams.cat.

You can use this prop in your Post component to call the appropriate child component. i.e Check if `this.props.routeParams.cat = a` , then call `<ComponentA />`.

Comment: Thank you! i was a little confused as to how it works, but i got it working now.